# Variable Size array with LAPACK/BLAS

Tags: c++, lapack, blas

MY Last question was not very clear . So posting it again.
I am trying to do matrix multiplication using BLAS routine dgemm. As the size of array that I wish to input to dgemm is not fixed, I am creating a variable size array. But this does not seem to work as I keep getting exception errors.
My code is as below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void dgemm_(const char *TRANSA, const char *TRANSB, const int *M, const int *N, const int *K, double *ALPHA, double **A, const int *LDA, double **B, const int *LDB, double *BETA, double **C, const int *LDC);

int main(void)
{
    int MatSize = 2;
    double **A= new double *[MatSize];
    double **B= new double *[MatSize]; 
    double **C= new double *[MatSize];
    for (int i=0; i<MatSize; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double[MatSize];
        B[i] = new double[MatSize];
        C[i] = new double[MatSize];
    }
    A[0][0] =  1;
    A[0][1]= 2;
    A[1][0] = 1;
    A[1][1]=2;
    B[0][0] = -2;
    B[0][1]= 3;
    B[1][0]= 2;
    B[1][1]= 2;
    char TRANS = 'N';
    char TRANS2 = 'N';
    double ALPHA = 1;
    double BETA = 0;
    dgemm_(&TRANS, &TRANS, &MatSize, &MatSize, &MatSize, &ALPHA, A, &MatSize, B, &MatSize, &BETA, C, &MatSize);
    cout << C[0][0] << C[0][1] << endl;
    cout << C[1][0] << C[1][1] << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Any inputs will be greatly helpful.

Comment: *"But this does not seem to work as I keep getting exception errors."* You should add those errors and use a debugger to know where the error happens.

Comment: No need to know the exceptions, as the code is wrong anyway. Lapack functions need arrays in one chunk of data, not pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to pass an array of arrays to dgemm, that is, an array of pointers (to arrays). Of course it's not possible, you must pass an array of doubles.

See [here](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/cblas/dgemm.c) for dgemm header, it needs double*, not double**.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am new to c++ so got few basic questions.  My idea here is to create a 2D array with variable size as the array size will not be known during compile time. So I used pointer-to-pointers. But I can not use that to input dgemm as you suggested. Is there any better way to create an unknown size of array?

Comment: malloc(m*n*sizeof(double) ? By the way, you can still use pointer to pointer, together with a "full array", just make your pointers point inside it.